# How to quit application using command line arguments inside a Task

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using electron 5.0.0 and I am trying to use windows JumpList and the Task category to quit my electron application.

```
    {
        program: process.execPath,
        arguments: '--new-window',
        iconPath: process.execPath,
        iconIndex: 0,
        title: 'New Window',
        description: 'Create a new window'
    }
])
```

I am trying to modify the example code from the electron website and i need to change the arguments

"arguments String - The command line arguments when program is executed."

I know windows has built in arguments like --new-window

So my question is does windows have something that will quit the application or do i need to make a custom argument if so how would i go about doing that

I want it to have the same functionality of skype see image
[image]

EDIT:

I tried using second-instance event but it does not seem to be called when the user clicks on the task

```
app.setUserTasks([
    {
        program: process.execPath,
        arguments: '--force-quit',
        iconPath: process.execPath,
        iconIndex: 0,
        title: 'Force Quit App',
        description: 'This will close the app instead of minimizing it.'
    }
])
app.on('second-instance', (e, argv)=>{
    console.log("secinst" + argv)
    if(argv === '--force-quit'){
        win.destroy();
    }

})
```

Comment: Try running `--help` instead of `--new-window` to see if there is a command to close the window because personally I don't know if there's a command to close the window or not. Let me know what happens afterwards!

Comment: Nothing happens I tried running it in a command prompt aswell. What i found out is in the SetUserTask the Program arg refers to the program that is going to be launched so basically what it does is it lauches the same program again with arguments. Its mean for something like "new window" in chrome where you can make a new window in it but does anyone know how to close the current application.

Comment: You should handle that command using [second-instance](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-second-instance) event.

Comment: @hijleh could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set tasks like this:

```
app.setUserTasks([
    {
        program: process.execPath,
        arguments: '--force-quit',
        iconPath: process.execPath,
        iconIndex: 0,
        title: 'Force Quit App',
        description: 'This will close the app instead of minimizing it.'
    }
])
```

When clicked, this will launch a new instance of your application with the command line argument `--force-quit`. You should handle that argument.

Your use case makes sense only if you allow a [single instance](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelock) of your application to be running. You need to get [`argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) from the [`second-instance`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-second-instance) event.

```
const { app } = require('electron')
let myWindow = null

const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()

if (!gotTheLock) {
  app.quit()
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', (event, argv, workingDirectory) => {
    // Someone tried to run a second instance
    const forceQuit = argv.indexOf("--force-quit") > -1;
    if (forceQuit) app.quit()
  })

  // Create myWindow, load the rest of the app, etc...
  app.on('ready', () => {
  })
}
```

Comment: So i tried implementing what you said. (i already prevented dual instances) but for some rason the second-instance is not being called and it opens the boilerplate application (https://i.gyazo.com/240c8a3e6b473a8fb246629787634036.png) and the second instance method listener is never called. I think the program path might be wrong but I don't know how to find the correct one. @hijeh

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out. process.execpath will only work when the application is properly build. I also had to use win.destroy() because quit will just minimize it because of some other code that i had.

Comment: I think you can also use app.exit() to force app close.